# XSLT grouping using child nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT mapping. I have a scenario where I need to group all the group based on a conditon from a child node. For example, I need to group the student group based on the result of the student and display how many have passed the exam and failed.
Please explain how for each group is also used.

```
<student>
<biodata>
<biodata_name>AAA</biodata_name>
<biodata_fname>Faaa</biodata_fname>
</biodata>
<marks>
<term1>
<term1_sub1>24</term1_sub1>
<term1_sub2>23</term1_sub2>
<term1_res>Pass</term1_res>
</term1>
</marks>
</student>
<student>
<biodata>
<biodata_name>BBB</biodata_name>
<biodata_fname>Fbbb</biodata_fname>
</biodata>
<marks>
<term1>
<term1_sub1>22</term1_sub1>
<term1_sub2>23</term1_sub2>
<term1_res>Pass</term1_res>
</term1>
</marks>
</student>
<student>
<biodata>
<biodata_name>CCC</biodata_name>
<biodata_fname>Fccc</biodata_fname>
</biodata>
<marks>
<term1>
<term1_sub1>14</term1_sub1>
<term1_sub2>13</term1_sub2>
<term1_res>Fail</term1_res>
</term1>
</marks>
</student>
```

I didn't understand grouping

Comment: Please post a **specific** question, not a request for tutorial.

Comment: Write your best attempt at a solution, and if it doesn't work, post your attempt, and then we can tell you what's wrong with it. Unless we know specifically why you are stuck, all we can do is point you at one of the many books and tutorials out there.